# Grouping in WPF datagrid without collection view

Tags: wpf, datagrid, collectionview

Is it possible to provide grouping in WPF datagrid with only observable collection? i mean without using collectionview?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can. Why can't you use a CollectionView?

Comment: it is possible to provite grouping in a datagrid without using literally the collectionview. but you will end up writing you own custom datagrid, then you will realize you will need an object that tells your custom datagrid what property names you wish to use for grouping. at the end you will end up reinventing the wheel of collectionview. so therefore no its not possible to do grouping in datagrid without collectionview.